# Imported functions from folder not running (repl.it)

Tags: import, replit

What title says. Even the AI acknowledges that I supposedly have the imports formatted properly but doesn't know what the error is and says to "check elsewhere" in the code.

[main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCtoQ.png)
[defs.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvwwV.png)

Thanks in advance.

I've looked up multiple Reddit and StackOverflow discussions on this and they all say to use star import. Some say to **init** to turn them into packages but I want to know the best way to get these functions (like getACode) to run from a star import of the Investigations folder.